# android HttpsURLConnection not initializing

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I have the following code for connecting to a url. My problem, is that when I run it in debug, I see that `connected = false` and none of the other parameters that I am trying to set are working (such as `timeout`). Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong??

And before anyone asks, my manifest has the internet permission.

```
private static class SyncOperation extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        String msg = "Good";
        int code = 0;
        try {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
            urlConnection =  (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            msg = "Bad MalformedURLException";
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("HTTPS", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            msg = "Bad IOException";
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("HTTPS", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            Log.d("HTTPS", msg);
            Log.d("HTTPS", "diconnected");
        }

        return code;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer code) {
        super.onPostExecute(code);

        Toast t = Toast.makeText(mContext, code.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only configuring your connection, but you don't connect it. The name of the method `url.openConnection()` is misleading: it does not open a connection. it only gives you a connection object, which is not connected initially.

You need to invoke any of the methods which cause the connection to connect, e.g. [connect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29).

In other words, try to actually do something with your connection, like reading the content and writing it to `System.out.println()`. That will open the connection automatically.